# Returning a variable from a function in php (return not working)

Tags: php

I'm building an XML page inside of a function, and for some strange reason I don't get the whole thing spit out of the function. I've tried

```
return $thisXml;
}
echo $thisXML;
```

and I only get the xml declaration which is in the variable before the function. 
If i put an echo in the function, i get everything back as I should.

my page essentially looks like this

```
$thisXml = 'xml declaration stuff';

function getThisXML($thisXML){
  for(i=1; i<5; i++){
  $query "has the 5 in it";

  while ($mysqlQuery =mysql_fetch_array($theQuery) {
    $thisXml.='add the xml';
  }
  $thisXml.='close the last element';
  return $thisXml;
}

echo $thisXml;
```

as i said, if I replace the 'return' with 'echo', I get all the nice xml. if I echo outside the function, I only get the original declaration.

really strange, and i've been struggling with this one all day.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
return $thisXml;
}
echo $thisXML;
```

$thisXML; only exists in the scope of the function.
Either make $thisXML; global (bad idea) or `echo getThisXML()` where getThisXML is the function that returns `$thisXML`;

Comment: thanks, you are correct, I need to echo the function, not just the variable (I didn't go the global route, I was trying to avoid that). 

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Are you actually calling the function in the sense of:

```
$thisXml = getThisXML($someinput);
```

Maybe a silly question, but I don´t see it in your description.

Comment: $thisXml = getThisXML() was not giving the answer in my case

Answer (score 4):

You need to invoke the function!

```
$thisXml = 'xml declaration stuff';

echo getThisXML($thisXML);
```

Or pass the variable by reference:

```
$thisXml = 'xml declaration stuff';

function getThisXML(&$thisXML){
  ...
  return $thisXml;
}

getThisXML($thisXML);
echo $thisXml;
```

Comment: yes, i was calling the function, forgot to put that in the code I entered above, sorry. my bad.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call the function and apply `echo` on the returned value:

```
 $thisXml = '…';
 echo getThisXML($thisXml);
```

Or you pass the variably by [reference](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a variable defined inside the function scope.

Use:

```
$thisXML;

function do(){
 global $thisXML;
 $thisXML = "foobar";
}

print $thisXML;
```

Answer (score 1):

Returning a variable doesn't mean that it affects that variable globally, it means the function call evaluates to that value where it's used.

```
$my_var = 5;

function my_func() {
  $my_var = 10;
  return $my_var;
}

print my_func();
print "\n";
print $my_var;
```

This will print

```
10
5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can create function in php this way:

<?php

$name = array("ghp", "hamid", "amin", "Linux");
function find()
{
    $find = 0;
    if(in_array('hamid', $name))
    {
      $find = 1;
      return $find;
    }
    else 
    {
      return $find;
    }
}


//###################
$answare = find();
echo $answare;
?>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! It's always better to include some explanation to the code in your answers, so that other users can understand it better :) For more info, please visit [ask]