# PHP Why Can't EOM contain PHP functions?

Tags: php, swiftmailer, heredoc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling PHP functions within HEREDOC strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104516/calling-php-functions-within-heredoc-strings)

I am using Swiftmailer PHP to create an order complete page. When the customer lands on this page, I use an include to a PHP file.

This page file has SwiftMailer EOM HTML that gets sent to the customer. However I have the HTML parts in chunks, so the header is via a function called header and order totals are the same too. I want to be able to include EOM functions inside the EOM. Is this possible?

```
Id  =       46088;

// MAIL FUNCTION
function mailToSend($Id){

// EOM CAN'T BE TABBED
$html = <<<EOM
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
getHeader($Id);
getOrderTotalBoxTable($Id);
</body>
</html>
EOM;


}

mailToSend(46088);
```

Comment: Could you not place the output of the function in to a variable and place that inside the heredoc?

Comment: What is `EOM` I have searched and I cannot find documentation about it

Comment: I can't tell you *why*, but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104516/calling-php-functions-within-heredoc-strings) is going to help you.

Comment: I’d suggest you look into templating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @deceze said, you can't, but this will work (extend @xenon comment to an example):

```
function getHeader($Id = '')
{
    $text = '';
    $text.=' Your first line of text, store it in an variable <br>';
    $text.= 'Hello '.$Id.'<br>';
    $text.='Your last text to be returned<br>';
    return $text;
}

// MAIL FUNCTION
function mailToSend($Id){

    $getHeader = getHeader($Id);
    $getOrderTotalBoxTable = getOrderTotalBoxTable($Id);

    // EOM CAN'T BE TABBED
$html = <<<EOM
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    $getHeader;
    $getOrderTotalBoxTable;
    </body>
    </html>
EOM;

}

mailToSend(46088);
```

Comment: Using this example, I have, example `$getHeader` as a function above, the code is like `function getHeader($oid){ echo 'hello'; }` so the email does send but it is blank at the function part, the page shows the `hello` do I need to put it in the global $html var??

Comment: I did not fully understood your question, but the function getHeader needs to return something, not print, something along these lines: "function getHeader($oid){ return 'hello '.$oid; }"

Comment: Can you show me an example, can I just do loads of returns??

Comment: You cannot do loads of returns.

Comment: Yes, so I made a $print variable inside the other function, and just did print="" and then print .="" etc and then then return $print is blank, but echo $print works... but echo does not include it inside the EOM

Comment: Links with this for future reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513511/returning-a-variable-from-a-function-in-php-return-not-working

Comment: Why I use return it only allows me to display one result - if I have MySQL loop inside it.. return only allows it to be used once...

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about are [**Heredocs**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) and they don't support function interpolation, only [variable interpolation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).

Comment: that will try to access a variable after a function is called?

Comment: Yes, corrected that statement.