# Is the PHP function command only limited to one use?

Tags: php, arrays, function, loops, reset

```
function getHeader($id){

    // VARS
    $print="";

    // SQL TO GET THE ORDER
    $mySQL=mysql_query("
    SELECT * FROM `table`
    ");

    // LOOP THE IDS 
    while($r=mysql_fetch_array($mySQL)){

    $print .=  '<p>'.$r["id"].'</p>';

    }
    return $print;
}

// MAIL FUNCTION
function mailToSend($Id){

        $getHeader = getHeader($Id);

$html = <<<EOM
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
        $getHeader;
        </body>
        </html>
EOM;

}

mailToSend(46088);


?>
```

My question relates to my previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917256/php-why-cant-eom-contain-php-functions)

Given that `$print` is looped and contains many rows. How can I ensure the return statement loops my data. I must use `return`.

Comment: Having a hard time trying to interpret your issue

Comment: you declare foo function with a $bar parameter yet you pass nothing to it. you recover its return value in the $foo variable yet you don't echo it... I don't understand...

Comment: i dont understand why are you passing id to getHeader() function when you are not using it anywhere in the funtion.

Comment: @BhavikShah It is an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used the result of the function "foo" incorrectly.
You should do it like this..

```
function show(){
    $foo =  foo();
    echo $foo;
}
```

EDIT: you also didn't pass any variable with the foo() - function and in your declaration in does requires a parameter $bar

Answer (score 2):

Do you understand the concept of [functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) and [scope of execution](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)?
After returning `$print`, the value of the variable will be assigned to `$foo`, $print wouldn't exist any more in th outer scope. You have to `echo $foo`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand you correctly but don't you want:

```
<?php

function show(){
    echo foo();
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you replace return with echo, there is no need to use array for that, as you have appended the content.

If you echo the content in the function itself, then there is no need to get the return value in another variable.

```
function foo($bar){

    // VARS
    $foo="Chocolate";
    $print="";

    // SQL TO GET THE ORDER
    $mySQL=mysql_query("
    SELECT * FROM `table`
    ");

    // LOOP THE IDS 
    while($r=mysql_fetch_array($mySQL)){

        $print .=  '<p>'.$r["id"].'</p>';

    }
    echo $print;
}


// call the function
// you dont need to have function show
foo();
```