# Get last ID on CRUD

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, crud

[UPDATED]

Ok, updating the question with full code and what I'm trying to do.

My table is on MySQL 5.7 - MyISAM

```sql
ID | user_name | user_email
```

With ID being auto-increment

And here is my code for conn, pdo and crud.

conn.php

```
<?php

define('HOST',     '127.0.0.1');
define('DBNAME',   'db_name');
define('CHARSET',  'utf8');
define('USER',     'db_user');
define('PASSWORD', 'bd_pw');

class Connection
{
  private static $pdo;
  private function __construct(){}

  public static function getInstance()
  {
    if(!isset(self::$pdo))
    {
      try
      {
        $conn_options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8', PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true);
        self::$pdo    = new PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.';dbname='.DBNAME.';charset='.CHARSET, USER, PASSWORD, $conn_options);
      }
      catch (PDOException $e)
      {
        echo 'Erro: '.$e->getMessage();
      }
    }
    return self::$pdo;
  }
}
```

tables.php

```
<?php

require_once 'class.conn.php';
require_once 'class.crud.php';

$pdo = Connection::getInstance();

$crud_usr = Crud::getInstance($pdo,'users');
```

crud.php (class and insert part)

```
<?php
# --------------------------------------------------
# Creating CRUD class
# --------------------------------------------------
class Crud
{
  private $pdo         = null;    # Storing PDO connection
  private $table       = null;    # Storing table name
  private static $crud = array(); # Static attribute that contains a self instance
  # --------------------------------------------------
  # Class constructor -> PUBLIC method
  # --------------------------------------------------
  public function __construct($connection, $table='default')
  {
    if(!empty($connection))
    {
      $this->pdo = $connection;
    }
    else
    {
      echo 'Conexão inexistente!';
      exit();
    }
    # ----------
    if(!empty($table) && $table !== 'default')
    {
      $this->table =$table;
    }
  }
  # --------------------------------------------------
  # Static public method that returns a Crud class instance
  # --------------------------------------------------
  public static function getInstance($connection, $table='default')
  {
    # Verifying if there's a class instance
    if(!isset(self::$crud[$table]))
    {
      try
      {
        self::$crud[$table] = new Crud($connection, $table);
      }
      catch (Exception $e)
      {
        echo 'Error '.$e->getMessage();
      }
    }
    return self::$crud[$table];
  }
  # --------------------------------------------------
  # Setting table name on $table
  # --------------------------------------------------
  public function setTableName($table)
  {
    if(!empty($table))
    {
      $this->table = $table;
    }
  }
  # --------------------------------------------------
  # SQL INSERT builder
  # --------------------------------------------------
  private function buildInsert($arrayData)
  {
    # Variables
    $sql    = '';
    $fields = '';
    $values = '';
    # Constructing instruction with loop
    foreach ($arrayData as $key => $value)
    {
      $fields .= $key.', ';
      $values .= '?, ';
    }
    # Removes comma from the end of the string
    $fields = (substr($fields, -2) == ', ') ? trim(substr($fields, 0, (strlen($fields) - 2))) : $fields;
    # Removes comma from the end of the string
    $values = (substr($values, -2) == ', ') ? trim(substr($values, 0, (strlen($values) - 2))) : $values;
    # Concatenating variables for instruction
    $sql .= "INSERT INTO {$this->table} (".$fields.")VALUES(".$values.")";
    # Returns string with SQL instruction
    return trim($sql);
  }
  # --------------------------------------------------
  # SQL INSERT function
  # --------------------------------------------------
  public function insert($arrayData)
  {
    try
    {
      # Insert SQL instruction built from method
      $sql = $this->buildInsert($arrayData);
      # Transfer instruction to PDO
      $stm = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
      # Loop for data as parameter
      $count = 1;
      foreach ($arrayData as $value)
      {
        $stm->bindValue($count, $value);
        $count++;
      }
      # Execute SQL instruction and returns
      $result = $stm->execute();
      return $result;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
      echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
    }
  }
```

When I use the insert:

new_user.php

```
<?php

$arrayInsert = array(
  'user_name' => $user_name,
  'user_email'=> $user_email
);
$return = $crud_usr->insert($arrayInsert);
# --------------------------------------------------
# I need to output a link like this
# --------------------------------------------------
echo '<a href="/profile.php?id='.%LAST_ID_INSERTED%.'">View profile</a>';
```

I know I need to use **lastInsertId()** from PDO.

I've tried to change this, but it doesn't work:

```php
# Execute SQL instruction and returns
$result = $stm->execute();
$last_id = $this->pdo->lastInsertId($sql);
return $result;
```

BUT when I do:

```
# Execute SQL instruction and returns
$result  = $stm->execute();
$last_id = $this->pdo->lastInsertId($sql);
return $last_id;
```

It works! But I'm worried about changing the return of the function.
So, I need to know if changing it is the correct way to do that.
I changed the inser too:

```
<?php

$arrayInsert = array(
  'user_name' => $user_name,
  'user_email'=> $user_email
);
$return = $crud_usr->insert($arrayInsert);
# --------------------------------------------------
# I need to output a link like this
# --------------------------------------------------
echo '<a href="/profile.php?id='.$return.'">View profile</a>';
```

So, it's working, but I don't know if it is the correct way of doing that, and if it may cause problems for my code in the future.

Regards

Comment: Your function returns the result of `$stm->execute();` which is a boolean. If you want to return something else, you'll need to do that, or set a property on the class that you can later reference with `$this->last_id`

Comment: As it stands, this sounds like a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513511/returning-a-variable-from-a-function-in-php-return-not-working) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848344/pdo-get-current-inserted-id)

Comment: @miken32 I believe you are right. Noticing that right now. Do you a have a suggestion to create that reference?

Comment: Are you trying to get the last id then add/append something to generate new id in the current `INSERT`? Or are you just getting the last id for display purpose? Is id inserted manually or should it be auto increment?

Comment: @tcadidot0 I updated the question with everything